# Angular 2 Unit Test for IF condition

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am new to unit testing. I am trying to unit test the if condition for the code below:

```
hide() {
        this.count --;
        if (this.count === 0) {
            this.loaderIs = false;
        }
    }
```

I am trying to use spy function on `loaderIs` variable.

```
it('hide function check', () => {
        expect(loaderService.hide).toBeDefined();
        spyOn(loaderService, 'loaderIs');
        loaderService.hide();
        expect(loaderService.loaderIs).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

Any input and guides are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

the thing is that you should not mock unit your are testing. (in your case it is `hide` method). Call of `hide` method should call actual method. Please see code below

```
describe('Some test: ', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        loaderService.loaderIs = false;
        // ...
    });

    it('loaderIs should be falsy', () => {
        loaderService.count = 1
        loaderService.hide();
        expect(loaderService.loaderIs).toBeFalsy();
    });

    it('loaderIs should be truthy', () => {
        loaderService.count = 2
        loaderService.hide();
        expect(loaderService.loaderIs).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```